# Do these equations represent the distance of a point from the origin on both axes?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[Triangle and the equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXKKX.png)

Does these equations somehow represent the distance between the leftmost point (assumed as origin) and the point (x,y), with the distance on the x axis being the first equation and the distance on the y axis being the second equation? If so, how; and if not, what do they represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a strange picture.

The formulas give the new coordinates of the point you get when you rotate the point $(x,y)$ through angle $\theta$. about the origin.

Try some examples to confirm that.

Comment: Yesi I knew I had seen this equation before! But, according to this page (http://danceswithcode.net/engineeringnotes/rotations_in_2d/rotations_in_2d.html), the signs of sines are different compared to my equations, why could that be?

Comment: @enlargedpeacock I'm not sure why. Perhaps it's the third bullet in the Common Errors section at the end of the post you link to. In any case you can get it right in your application with a few tests.

Comment: I see, that is probably why. Thank you!